# Can someone please help me identify these chips?

Tags: hardware-rec

I unburdened some old hardware. I don't know exactly what kind of hardware component it is. I guess it's some RAM chip, but don't know which kind, or size.

Can you help me ?

The first one :

[image]

The second:

[image]

Comment: @michalkjorling : I didn't put "Ram" in the title, because I was quite sure the second was not RAM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to identify an item in a picture are not searchable or useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, Googling the references printed in the body of such component will raise several good results.

For instance, I found this for the first one, searching for `TM497MBK36Q-60`:

http://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/tm497mbk36q-60/243023711368513027/

This one is a "4M X 36 FAST PAGE DRAM MODULE, 60 ns, SMA72", from Texas Instruments High-Performance Analog.

I'm still doing some researches for the second one.

**[UPDATE]**

The second one looks like a cache module for PC chips M919, for 486 motherboards. Here are the links that helped me to identify this :

http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=43183

http://www.ebay.com/itm/201243815960

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

The first one has the model number [TM497MBK36Q](https://www.ti.com/product/tm497mbk36q) printed on it. The TM497MBK36Q is a 16 MiB 72-pin SIMM with 9 bits/byte (the ninth bit is for either parity or ECC; Texas Instruments says parity), which makes sense.

The second one didn't have any obvious markings good enough to Google for (but it turns out I might have been wrong about that). It does however use nine [AS7C256-15JC](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/82663/ALSC/AS7C256-15JC.html) chips, which are 32 KiB (256 kibibit) each CMOS SRAMs according to [this data sheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/82663/ALSC/AS7C256-15JC.html). That means it's most likely a 256 KiB SRAM module with parity or ECC. SRAM can be found in high-performance subsystems like cache because it is much faster than DRAM, but also a lot more expensive per megabyte.

As Ob1lan mentioned, in general, using your favorite search engine to search for the chip or module markings will quickly get you pretty close to an answer.